# How to connect to the Internet via 3g-usb-modem in terminal FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, 3g

In FreeBSD GUI is not installed by default and I have to install it manually. In order to install the GUI I need the Internet and I have only 3g-usb-modem Huawei E171. I don`t know how to connect to the internet via 3g-usb-modem in terminal FreeBSD.